# Selenium Hover/Click event on ajax filled menu options

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Having serious issues here. Someone please help.

I am trying to login to a website. - This Works!

Redirect to the page I want after Login - This Works!

Now once in, I have to **hover over** the **settings icon** so the dropdown shows, and then click on the **"Settings"** options that has **NO ID or CLASS or HREF**.

Now there is a couple of reasons I cant do this. Number 1 is if I try to click on the link after the hover, it tells me that it's hidden and I cant interact with it. Also the menu options in the form are populated and appended once you hover, through ajax I think. They are not on the initial page load.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) 

box = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "yucs-help_button"))) 

menuButton = driver.find_element_by_id("yucs-help_button") 

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(menuButton).perform()
```

After the above code is deployed I print the driver.page_source and can see (below) that the new menu options are there, if you don't hover, the below code will not be on the page.

Now the `<a>` i'm trying to click is the `<span>Settings</span>` option, and for the life of me, it will not work. Either can't find it, not clickable, can't interact with it, etc, etc, etc. `xpath`, `css_selector`, `partial_name`, nothing finds this thing. Also whats weird is once you click on it, from a browser, it appends an ID to `<span>` So weird. Any ideas?

```
<a data-ylk="rspns:nav;t3:tl-lst;t5:custitm;slk:custitm;elm:itm;elmt:custitm;itc:0;cpos:2" class="C(#000)! Td(u):h " data-mad="options" data-customevt="true" href="#" data-rapid_p="18"><span>Settings</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform `mouse over` event on element you should try to use `.execute_script()` using following `java script` :-

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) 
box = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "yucs-help_button"))) 
menuButton = driver.find_element_by_id("yucs-help_button") 

driver.execute_script("var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');clickEvent.initEvent('mouseover', true, true); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(clickEvent);", menuButton)
```

Now after successfully `mouse over` you should try to click on `Settings` link as below :-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Settings')]/parent::a[@data-mad = 'options']").click()
```

Hope it will help you..:)